# What's the difference of pData1 and pData2, which are build as follows

Tags: c++, c

What's the difference of pData1 and pData2, which are build as follows:

> pData1 = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));
>
> int * pData2 = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));

Comment: @Justin: Don't be so quick to "fix" code. The missing asterisk may have been his question. :X

Comment: sorry, a typo, I have modified it.

Comment: Check the old rev's - I didn't fix the code, just made it readable

Comment: @JustinEthier - you did modify the code.  In rev 1, it was `int pData2` and then you changed it to `int *pData2`.

Comment: OK, I see what you all are talking about now. The markup was never changed from `int *pData2 = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));` - but if you look at the old revs, the marked up code (in the bottom box) does not have the `*` in the original rev. Looks like a bug in SO (!!)

Comment: @user297850: If you don't mind, could you completely re-type the entire question? There's too much confusion going on. Make sure you get everything down to the character. :) If there are any formatting errors, I will fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more information, it would appear the only difference is that `pData2` is local to the allocation since it is declared as an `int *`. `pData1` is not declared so it would have to have a larger (global?) scope and be defined elsewhere.

Comment: Er, isn't the really big problem the fact that the allocated memory is being typecast to a non-pointer type?

Comment: Without knowing what type `pData1` is, it is impossible to know if it is a non-pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

The first is (presumably) an assignment to an already-existing variable named "pData1".

The second declares a new variable named "pData2", and initialises it.

Other than that, I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pData1 is a pointer (int*), it can be dereferenced with *, and points to an int who's value is 0.
pData2 will point to a new int also, who's value is zero, but cannot be dereferenced without casting to a pointer first, with something like:

```
*(int*)(pData2) = 4;
```

ie: you can't change/get the value the pData2 points to with something like `*pData2 = 4;`